# Compile OpenCL kernels with debug information?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

How can I compile opencl kernels with debug information?
If i do it like hear [debugging](http://samritmaity.wordpress.com/tag/opencl-debugging/)

[const char* options = "-g";

clBuildProgram( *hProgram, 0, 0, options,NULL,NULL);]:

i get following error:

clang: Unknown command line argument '-g'.  Try: 'clang --help'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"-g" is not a supported build option in OpenCL, see section 5.4.3/5.6.3 (version 1.0/1.1 respectively) of the specification for a list of the supported options.

If you're targetting a CPU then "-g" may work but is unsupported. For debugging on GPUs you could check out [gDEBugger CL](http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php) perhaps, I've not tried it though. NVIDIA's [Parallel Nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html) (formerly codenamed Nexus) has OpenCL profiling features in the beta and will support OpenCL debugging.

Comment: I have already seen, that opencl spec doesn't discribe any"-g" option.

It meens, that gDEBugger doesn't need any additional iformation for debugging of kerneles? Has somebody expirience with this tool? At the moment it doesn't work properly with my programs.

Answer (score 3):

"-g" is a feature, which is supported by ati-GPUs